# Prove that $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ and $f'(x)\le g'(x)$ for $x\ge x_0$ implies $f(x)\le g(x)$ for $x\ge x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

> Suppose that
> $$
> f (x_0) = g(x_0)
> $$
> and that
> $$
> f'(x)\le g'(x), \qquad x \ge x_0.
> $$
> Then show that
> $$
> f(x)\le g(x), \qquad x \ge x_0.
> $$

---

This is an "obvious" fact if one assumes that the second equation means that $g$ grows faster than $f$  on $[x_0, \infty)$ (or at least as fast). But how would you go about to prove this from the definitions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar with the mean value theorem?

Comment: @Integrand Yes it does!

Comment: @ECL could you please expand a little?